# Energy formula for finite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, potential, schroedinger-equation

The energy formula for infinite potential well is $$E=\frac{n^2h^2}{8ma^2},$$where $m$ is the mass of the particle, $a$ is the width of the well but in the case of finite potential well, I actually went to search online for the energy formula but to no avail. Does anybody here knows the formula for it?

Comment: There is no analytic formula. Wave function matching at the potential well boundaries leads to a transcendental equation, which can only be solved numerically.

Comment: About half way down [Wikipedia's page on the Finite Potential Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well) it states "The energy equations cannot be solved analytically.".  Please do some basic research before posting.

Comment: Finite walled potential well by Hyperphysics: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/pfbox.html

Answer (score 3):

There is no clean analytical formula for the eigen-energies of the finite potential well. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well) explains, the quantization condition for that problem reduces to a transcendental equation of the form
$$
\sqrt{u_0^2 - v^2} = v\tan(v),
$$
where $u_0$ is a fixed number and $v=kL/2$, a proxy for the energy $E=\hbar^2k^2/2m$, is the variable you're solving for. (This is for symmetric wavefunctions; antisymmetric wavefunctions have a modified but similar equation.) This transcendental equation does not admit a clean solution in terms of elementary functions, and it is messy enough that it doesn't even make much sense to tabulate the solutions as special functions (the way you get, for example, tabulations of the zeros of Bessel functions).

Thus, if you want the actual values, there's nothing for it but to solve equation $(1)$ numerically. And if it makes you uncomfortable that such an easy-to-pose problem is not solvable, then, well, welcome to quantum mechanics!